# Subtract a different number from each column in an array

Tags: python

Assuming I have the following array in Python:

```
x = np.array(([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]))
x
```

Which looks like:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

I have an array `mu`, which is the mean of each of the columns of array `x`

```
mu = x.mean(axis =0)
```

Which looks like:

```
array([5., 6., 7., 8.])
```

Now, I want a new array `x_demean`, where the first column gets subtracted by its own mean, second column by its own mean, and so one.
The result should look like:

```
array([[ -4,  -4,  -4,  -4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4])
```

Comment: numpy's [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) automatically does this for you when you simply use the operator!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple `x - mu` which provides the desired output.

You can use the proper `subtract()` method of **numpy** also. Refer the docs [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html).

Try this code:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array(([1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]))
mu = x1.mean(axis =0)
x_demean = np.subtract(x1, mu)
print(x_demean) #use x_demean.astype(int) if you want integer array
```

Answer (score 3):

`x-mu` is all you need to get what you want.

If you want output strictly as integers, do `(x-mu).astype(int)`

**Output**

```
array([[-4, -4, -4, -4],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  4,  4,  4]])
```